# Spring Cloud - how to allow access to endpoint for specific microservice only?

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, microservices, spring-cloud

I have simple microservice architecture:

- edge service
- service registry
- auth service (I am using JWT and OAuth2)
- user service
- frontend and some core services

When the user tries to log in, the credentials are passing from edge service to auth service. Auth service fetches user's data from user service (using **@FeignClient**) and if username/password matches, it generates token. Nothing fancy about it.

There a 'little' problem with this approach: the endpoint `/api/user/{username}` in user service, which is used by auth service to fetch user's data, might be used by any user to get any other user's data (password, roles etc.). The one solution would be somehow create JWT token for auth-service with role `AUTH_SERVICE` and at the user service side check JWT and if the role is different than `AUTH_SERVICE` reject the request.

Are there any other solutions?

**EDIT**

I thought that my design is quite common but apparently I should have been more specific in the first place:

- Auth-servie is my Authorization Server and the other services are Resource servers
- I use API gateway pattern and my auth-service is also behin proxy
- After the client application obtains JWT it adds it to every request and based on that the authentication and authorization is performed; every Resource server has a public key which is used to verify signature; if it's valid, the service knows that JWT has been generated by trusted auth-service and the service based on JWT creates OAuth2Authenication object which contains all the user information

**EDIT2:**

I ended up merging auth-service to user-service, which was the suggestion given from a couple of SO users. After thinking about it it seemed unnecessary to have a seperate auth-service for just JWT generation. I've accepted @Abhijit Sarkar answer because it has some valid points even though he wasn't right about additional call to auth-service to verify validity of the token.

Comment: Users shouldn't be allowed to retrieve other users data to start with. To call the /api/user endpoint a user first has to be authorised, so that he only can retrieve his own data. Authorisation is done by the auth service, so consider moving that functionality out of the userservice to the auth service. Retrieving the password/roles from an other service sounds bad, this should be the responsibility of the auth service.

Comment: That's all valid points and I'm quite aware of all of it. It's just that I have an architecture I described above and was interested if it's possible to keep user-service and auth-service seperated and still have secure application. I think it is possible (I've read about OAuth scope, that's the way) but now I begin to wonder if it wouldn't be better to change the architecture. I'll think about it - thanks.

Comment: In addition to my answer below, you may want to look into this article: http://www.baeldung.com/sso-spring-security-oauth2

Comment: Thank you. But just to clarify after you edit: I really know where my Authorization server is. I tried to explain it, but it apparently I failed - it's the auth-service. Also, after our chat I run my application and it turns out that I am right: after auth-service generates the JWT I can shut it down and then, using JWT, I can access some secured resources in my other services (which are Resources servers). Best example of this architecture can be found here https://github.com/mavogel/uaa-behind-zuul-sample/tree/integration-resource-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me that you split your services too thin; this happens, and with time, you start to realize that the services need to be more coarse-grained because of maintenance and performance issues. The cost of another HTTP call from auth to user service, and the overhead of maintaining inter-service auth is not trivial.

IMO, user service can exist for other user information, like address etc if those exist, but auth service should be responsible for managing its own data. This is exactly why Spring Security has a [UserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html).

This is really a design choice whether the user credentials and other user information should be in the same table, or even the same database. Different people will give you different answers, but in my opinion and experience, a shared database between a **small** number of **related** services is acceptable, especially because these tables are gonna be related by a foreign key (userId). Distributed transaction is pure evil with microservices so I'm not even going there. When you delete/update a user, go for eventual consistency using events.

**Edit**:

After chatting with the OP, I learned that user service is really the OAuth resource server in his design. It's not clear to him, and thus to me, where is the OAuth authorization server. Regardless, I stand by my suggestion to merge the user service and the auth service.

Comment: Actually, because I use JWT the number of calls between auth-service and user-service shouldn't be the problem: once auth-service generates JWT I have all I need to authorize and authenticate my users.

Comment: The call from auth to user service **will** happen in your design, regardless of whether you use JWT or whatever. Everything I said above still holds good. JWT is a token passed in a header, that's all.

Comment: That's true, I don't have much experiance in dealing with microservices but I've read two books about it and a number of articles so luckily I was able to avoid problems with distributed transactions. Your idea with shared database is interesting, I have to think about it. Thanks

Comment: Ah, the new buzzword in town, every company now wants to move to microservices, though if you ask them, a majority wouldn't be able to describe it :)

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda the thing :) But it doesn't have to be a bad idea. Probably I don't understand all of microservice architeture but still it's an interesting concept  and a chance to explore new technologie, new approaches. For sure it 's a good experiance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148704/discussion-between-pzeszko-and-abhijit-sarkar).

Answer (score 1):

It would be way better to **use the same DB** in auth & user service. Auth service just needs to access the credential.

You can even have a security layer at User service to implement the access control over the URI according to the role.

You need something like this:

1. Define a prefilter in edge service
2. Edge service gets authentication request and forwards it to authentication service.
3. Auth service uses the same DB as of User service to authenticate the user and generates JWT token.
4. All other requests would have the token in the request header.
5. Edge service shares the key by which JWT token was created or has a public key to verify the signature.
6. Edge service verifies the token in its prefilter and adds user info in the request header in the plain. Redirects request to required service.
7. Service takes the request and in its security filter, it uses user information from header to enforce the access control over resources.

Comment: That's a cool answer, upvoted - thanks. Actually I have successfully used this approach in my other project. In the end, in my current project I decided to merge auth-service to user-service.

Comment: I'd not involve these many service in authentication and authorization. In this approach, every service has to do some kind of security processing in order for a request to be successfully executed. If something changes (like JWT token format), all the services are impacted, which is a telltale sign of coupling.

Comment: No, just edge service needs to have capabilities to process JWT token. As I have mentioned in my answer, all other services would get user information in the plain format(not a token). They can refer to whatever information they need(like UserId, roles) and use it to enforce security.

On your comment **every service has to do some kind of security processing** I would say that it is a best practice to have a security layer in every service but services shouldn't be dependent on JWT.